# openerp form view don't display field data

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I found a problem with the **stock** module.
I want to add some fields
the data are well **stored** in the database but they are **not displayed** in the *view*!
you find files module test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>

        <record id="view_picking_out_form_test" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.picking.out.form.test</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking.out</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
                <field name="test" placeholder="e.g. [0-9][a-zA-Z]"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
        </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

test.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class stock_picking_out(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking.out'
    _columns = {
        'test': fields.char('Test Field', size=8, select=True, states={'done': [('readonly', True)]}, domain=[('type', '=', 'out')]),
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In stock module `view_picking_form` is inherited in other form and  replace pratner_id field and add domain 
form id view_picking_in_form

Line No. 1020

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="replace">
     <field name="partner_id" on_change="onchange_partner_in(partner_id)" string="Supplier" domain="[('supplier','=',True)]" />
</xpath>
```

So your field display only when partner is Supplier

You can use another field for position

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='stock_journal_id']" position="before">
      <field name="test" placeholder="e.g. [0-9][a-zA-Z]"/>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your custom module files are not being loaded.
To confirm this is so, add some random text to your XML file, to make it invalid.
If you are able to install/upgrade it without error, there's something wrong with your _*openerp*_py or addons path.